# what number is greater than x and falls after position y

Tags: r

Which number of x is > 5 and falls after the 10th position?  It is the number in position 11.
But I find myself writing a long code to get to the answer and I am wondering if there is a quicker way.

```
x <- c(5,7,3,6,9,4,1,4,7,10,8,5,7,9,7,1, 8, 4, 4,9);
```

Identify the location of all numbers >5 call it x1:

```
x1 <- which(x>5);
```

Identify the first number of the locations(x1) that occurred after 10th position:

```
first(which(x1 >10))
```

this identifies location 6 of x1;

identify the location of that number in the original vector (x):

```
x1[first(which(x1 >10))];
```

now we have the position of the value we want in the original vector (x), and this code pulls the value we want:

```
x[x1[first(which(x1 >10))]]
```

This seems like a very long code to answer a simple question, do you know shorter/simpler way to get to same results?

Comment: Can you please fix up all the syntax errors in your code. R is case sensitive, so `x` and `X` are not the same `object` and `c` and `C` are not the same either.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you think that `first` is a function. Is it in some package that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: sorry Joran, its an xts function

Comment: mnel, I pasted my question from a word editor, didn't notice it had capitalized some of the letters.  The two letters of the first line of code that were capitalized in error were fixed.

Comment: Stop using Word immediately - it is not a code editor! At the very least notepad or wordpad on windows would be almost infinitely better than Word for coding. There are plenty of free editors that are R-aware, consider using one of them: http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with some very simple indexing and subseting?

This gives the indices of all elements in `x` greater than 5 and which occur after position `10`:

```
> which(x > 5 & seq_along(x) > 10)
[1] 11 13 14 15 17 20
```

So the ultimate Answer is

```
> which(x > 5 & seq_along(x) > 10)[1]
[1] 11
```

or

```
> head(which(x > 5 & seq_along(x) > 10), 1)
[1] 11
```

The trick used here is to generate a vector of indices of `x` using the `seq_along()` function. That way we can generate all the matches in a single logical statement, and then select the first of these.

If you want to extract the identified element then:

```
> want <- which(x > 5 & seq_along(x) > 10)[1]
> x[want]
[1] 8
```

[It wasn't clear whether you wanted to identify which element met your criteria or the value of that element.]

Comment: @user2004820 if so, please consider accepting the Answer. See the [ask] section of the [faq] for details on how to do this and why it is a useful thing for the [so].

Answer (score 1):

An alternative version using [functional](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/funprog.html) programming to extract the index:

```
> Find(function(y) x[y] > 5 & y > 10, seq_along(x))
[1] 11
```

or to extract the element:

```
> x[Find(function(y) x[y] > 5 & y > 10, seq_along(x))]
[1] 8
```

Don't know about difference in performance compared with simple indexing, though.

Comment: Thanks mbask, I just looked back at this and realized it's "different".  I like it as an another way of looking at this.